# Is there a secret meaning in PPAP song?

Tags: words, conjunctions

I wonder if [PPAP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0E00Zuayv9Q) song by [Kazuhito Kosaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daimaou_Kosaka) actually has a secret meaning?

As far as I know, words in Japanese can mean several different things depending on their conjuctions or one's interpretation.

**Question:** Is there a secret second meaning in words like "Pen-Pineapple-Apple-Pen" when translated into Japanese language and/or written in a certain way?

Comment: One famous kind of apple is Fuji. It stands for Japan. Another is Red Delicious. The meaning is that Japan should embrace Communism. "This is a pen" is a famous textbook English sentence in Japan; since the true Japanese used brushes, "pen" stands for America. The pen is mightier than the sword, so America beat the Japanese samurai spirit. This is the "uh!" of pen penetrating apple.  Pineapples in old language are 鳳梨, phoenix pears. Phoenix is China and pears are golden = 金 = Kim = North Korea. American missile-pens aim for them next. It's a deeply political song. (This comment is 100% false.)

Comment: Anyway, we Japanese are taught at first that the phrase "This is a pen." is an English language. This fact seems to make us familiar with this song.

Comment: @mackygoo  Pikotarou doesn't say "This is a pen" but "I have a pen".

Comment: Yuuichi Tam This is "a pen". So we are familiar with the pharse I have "a pen". Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the song doesn't have any secret meanings.

I saw his interview about the song. He has made songs with a computer. One day he sat in front of a desk in order to make a song. He had already made the rhythm of the song at that time, so he only needed to make the lyrics of the song. When he was listening to the rhythm, he had a pen and there was an apple on the desk. He happened to stick the pen into the apple and thought this was an "apple pen".

He likes puns. The words "apple" and "pineapple" are similar, so he thought the pronunciation of "Pen-Pineapple-Apple-Pen" was interesting.